Trying to find open Black Line wire from a light switch to an outlet
have an open Line wire from a light switch to an outlet in a bedroom. My Klein ET450 has not been as great so far, had a false reading opened the wall to find an intact solid wire. looking for any tips about what to do to find the Junction box or open location with my problem wire.

There were many ways to interpret this information with so little capitalization and punctuation. I took a shot at parsing it. If my interpretation is not what you meant, please edit to show what you meant. And as Crip659 says, you may not be legally allowed to work on this problem unless you are a licensed electrician, because of the condo status. Call you local permitting authority.

FWIW a half-tripped breaker is a tripped breaker. The handles of some breakers go to a midway position when tripped. Forcing the breaker back on ("Resetting was odd") may have meant pushing electricity into a short, which might detonate the occupancy sensor and damage the breaker.

Where are you located?

Thanks for clarifying the issue you're having. I removed some personal information not pertinent to the problem. What is "L1", and why is the voltage 99, when the first sentence says you're looking for 120?

A tracer is a not a volt meter that is why it goes to 99 not 99 volts. L1 line voltage I don't understand this forum... you act like you're my mom. I know for sure there is a problem in one section of the wall. I appreciate the help we are on a diy site so obviously we are not electricians you included...

The way DIY.SE works is, we try to answer questions as best we understand them. But the question needs to be understandable. And it has taken some time to get this question to an understandable state. Also, personal "what I have been doing lately" and thanks statements are considered off topic. Personal attacks ("you're my mom") are grounds for censure.


my tracer showed no continuity indicating a short

Actually, that's backwards. If you have a short then you will show continuity where there should not be continuity - between hot and neutral (or between two hots on different legs/phases).
When there is no continuity where there is supposed to be continuity then you have:

A broken wire (unusual, but can happen)

or

A bad connection - whether a screw (and the wire wasn't in very well and slipped out), wire nut (not twisted properly), backstab (notorious for problems) or some other connection that isn't connecting.

